# Exporting charts from poi using itext

Tags: java, apache-poi, itext

I use apache poi and itext to export excel to pdf. Everything works fine for cells but now I also need to process excel charts and embedded images. Is it possible? If yes, I would need some hints.

Comment: i am not sure if it works and didn't try it myself. but i'd think you will have read the bytes of the chart/picture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert the whole excel to PDF, and then extract the images from the pdf.

Comment: The OP tries to program a routine *to export excel to pdf*; his issue happens while implementing that step.

Comment: There are no method build in Apache poi to export the excel to pdf. This is the reason I had to build one...

Comment: This post was very useful for the first part of the method I've built. My method also handle formulas, cell styles, cell spans. Is not so simple as in the example for complex documents :).  Now I need to also handle charts and images...